# Printing quotation mark not in whole std::string in C++ gives negative ASCII value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm running into a problem when reading from a file. Here is some sample code:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::string str1) {

    //... split the string up by spaces into vector "split"

    for (auto& str : split) {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
        std::cout << str[0] << "\n";
    }
});
```

So basically I print each element of split out on one line, and then print the first character. What I get is this:

```
“test test test
?
```

where the first line is the whole `str`, and the second line should be the first character. However, it prints a `?` instead. Even using a `std::string` will give the same result:

```
for (auto& str : split) {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
        std::cout << std::string(1, str[0]) << "\n";
}
```

I'm using `clang++ -std=c++11` as my setup. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: For the file I'm using all strings are guaranteed not empty.

Comment: @remyabel It is basically the chosen answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string is probably not encoded one element => one character. I was able to reproduce your issue [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/286868271cc73c6e) and it looks like the special quotation mark takes the first three string bytes, so this would print it properly:

```
std::cout << s.substr(0, 3);
```

Your situation could be a bit different, but I'm guessing it's UTF-8 for both you and Coliru. Specifically, the character looks to be [this one](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+201c/properties), the "left double quotation mark", with a UTF-8 value of 0xE2809C.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get it so that I can check if `char c == '\"';`?

Comment: @user473973, If you want a standard `"`, the same as you use for string literals in your code, I'd probably go for some normalize function (or I might be ignorant and none of them do quotation marks). If that's the case and you know you're getting UTF-8, you can look at the bit patterns yourself to find that character and convert it. Still, I don't imagine you should *have* to do that.

Comment: It should be noted, that this isn't a general solution to this problem. In fact, it's "quick hack", to make the second statement `std::cout << str[0] << "\n";` work under the very special circumstances. For example, if the first character would be different and wouldn't be a 3-byte UTF-8 character, this hack won't work anymore.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, That's a valid point. A proper library would help there, too.

Comment: By the way, your test program is "implementation defined": you are creating a string literal which does not only consist of characters which are in the _basic source character set_, which is a sub set of ASCII. The mapping from source files to the _source character set_ however, is "implementation defined". In other words, your test program is not universally valid. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, Yes indeed. I kind of assumed UTF-8 anyway, so it should be `u8"..."`.

Comment: Yes, `u8"..."` creates a UTF-8 string literal - representing the given string, e.g. "“uü”" in the _source character set_ (presumable UTF-8) - no matter of the current _execution character set_ (internal representation of strings).

Comment: Edit: in my former comment it should read: "The mapping from _source characters set_ to the _execution character set_ however, is "implementation defined".